# JavaScript API to create Svelte elements instead of a template

Tags: javascript, svelte

Svelte’s templating language is great, in that it looks like HTML. However, for highly dynamic content I need to be able to use the full power of JavaScript, not just `#if` and `#each`. For example, given a tree data structure, I want to generate hierarchical table headings. ([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jmakeig/kcrqbf47/246/)) In React most apps use JSX templates, but you can drop down to `createElement` if you need to. Is there a similar path for Svelte? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the DOM node, you can:

1. Add `bind:this={node}` to get access to the DOM node:

```html
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    let node

    onMount(() => {
        const dynamic = document.createElement('a')
        dynamic.innerHTML = "Click me!"

        node.appendChild(dynamic)   
    })
</script>

<div bind:this={node}/>
```

2. Add a `use` directive, this will also get you access to the raw DOM node

```html
<script>
    function ninja(node) {
        node.innerHTML = "Kawabunga!"
    }
</script>

<div use:ninja/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the `<svelte:self>` element, which allows you to create elements that call themselves recursively.

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self